# Multiple movie files MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have multiple moviefiles. That i would like to make a playlist of. How can i assign the next and previous buttons to go to the next movie.

I've tried to find a solution for this for a long time, but i cant seem to find a answer for this?

And i'm not talking about dismissing the current MPMoviePlayerController and opening a new one with the new video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **contentURL** property of MPMoviePlayerController for playing new video.

> If you set this property while a movie is playing, that movie pauses and the new movie begins loading. The new movie starts playing at the beginning.